# iText pdf generation in java: specific design

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to achive a specific design to generate a specific design using iText in java. The design is:

[image]

Can this be achived on the pdf and how?

Comment: yes ​‌‍           ​  ​‌‍           ​

Comment: well, that wasn't in your question

Comment: Have you google or try it? Have you read itext documentation? If you haven't, please do so.

Comment: http://itextpdf.com/book/ is this the link

Comment: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=202

Comment: The Vertical text example is slightly different from what is asked ;-) But the link to my book and the examples should help. Chapter 3 and the different showTextAligned methods are what is needed.

Comment: itext in Action 2nd Edition